# SFDX ERROR: You do not have access to the [ScratchOrgInfo] object

Tags: salesforcedx

I'm a SFDX/GitHub newbie, following the instructions on [Migrating an existing project from a production org to DX/Git repo](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/07/migrating-existing-projects-salesforce-dx.html). Everything is going well until I try to spin up the scratch org...

```
pmcclellan$ sfdx force:org:create -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a myscratchorg
```

and then I get the error:

```
ERROR:  You do not have access to the [ScratchOrgInfo] object.
```

I have searched this error here and elsewhere, and the consensus solution is that either the devhub isn't authorized, or the user doesn't have appropriate permissions on the devhub org. I have triple-checked both those conditions:

I have assigned the Manage Environment Hub permission set to myself, and I have re-authorized the dev hub with the CLI (subsequent to setting the permission set):

```
pmcclellan$ sfdx force:auth:web:login -d -a myhuborg
```

I have verified that the org is authorized with...

```
sfdx force:org:list
```

... and the org shows up with the correct alias, username, org Id and shows Connected.

I have verified that project-scratch-def.json exists in the /config/ directory:

```
{
    "orgName": "pmcclellan Company",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "orgPreferences" : {
        "enabled": ["S1DesktopEnabled"]
    }
}
```

I'm out of things I can think of to try. Any tips?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74361/discussion-on-question-by-patmcclellan-c-sfdx-error-you-do-not-have-access-to).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the discussion on this question is no longer accessible, so I hope I am not treading ground that's already been reviewed.

Reviewing the permissions in a fresh SFDX Dev Hub trial organization may be helpful. Those orgs come with a single permission set ("Salesforce DX") that does nothing save to provide the following object access:

> Active Scratch Orgs: Read, Edit, Delete
>   Namespace Registries: Read, Create, Edit, Delete
>   Scratch Org Infos: Read, Create, Edit, Delete

These are just object permission settings, not system-level permissions. (The Manage Environment Hub permission is not available in these trial orgs).

Does your permission set provide these object permissions?